# Getting the list of checked items in Ext JS 5 Grid always returns an empty array?

Tags: javascript, extjs, treeview, checked

Here is the relevant code from the view file:

```
Ext.define('MARS.view.listings.SummarySetupView', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'summarysetupview',

requires: [
    'MARS.view.listings.SummarySetupController'
],

controller: 'summarysetup',

title: "Summary",
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'deliverablesGridPanel'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Submit',
        handler: 'onSubmit'
    }
]
});
```

Here is the relevant code from the controller file:

```
Ext.define('MARS.view.listings.SummarySetupController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.summarysetup',

onSubmit: function () {

    console.log(this.getView().refs.gridDeliverables.getChecked());
    // Returns [] - empty array
}
});
```

And here is the definition of my xtype "deliverablesGridPanel":

```
Ext.define('MARS.view.DeliverablesGridPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.TreePanel',
xtype: 'deliverablesGridPanel',

title: 'Deliverables',
reference: 'gridDeliverables',
flex: 1,
autoScroll: true,
rootVisible: false,
bind: {
    store: '{jobTreeStore}'
},
columns: [
    {
        xtype: 'treecolumn',
        dataIndex: 'Name',
        text: 'Name',
        width: 200
    },
    {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'Description',
        text: 'Description',
        flex: 1
    }
]
});
```

It clearly knows that it is a grid because the function works, it just always returns empty...

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox selection columns in grids are usually part of a selection model. I know from old extjs3 days you would do something like grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections() and that would achieve what you are trying to do here.